# Not looping through array to match values

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason my code isn't working, I've used this type of code a thousand times and for whatever reason it's not matching.. When the column is blank however it does seem to match? Any suggestions on how I can change this or even improve this as I do realise 140,000 records is quite a lot!

```
Dim name1(140000) As String, name2(140000) As String, answer(140000) As String

For i = 1 To 140000
    name1(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet0").Cells(i, 1).value
    name2(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).value
    answer(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet0").Cells(i, 13).value

    If name1(i) = name2(i) Then

        answer(i) = "yes"

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why are you first adding the names to `name1()` and `name2()` and then checking for a match? Is your only goal to check if the names match?

Comment: Hi @DragonSamu, from the second row the name are added, if the names match between the two sheets to then have the 13th column display "yes" on the match row.

Comment: wouldn't pasting a formula in the entire range be faster?

Comment: I'm not sure as I've never tried with a formula, but even still, the above code should work? I don't understand why it isn't working in the first place.

Comment: What error do you get? You might need to declare your `i` variable as `Long`.

Comment: You are assigning to `anser(i)` a value before checking if both names match. See the third row within the for loop.

Comment: 1. A formula is the right way to go. 2. Also what happens if you replace `Activeworkbook` with `Thisworkbook`? 3. Instead of looping through ranges, do you know that you can assign the range to the array in one go?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies, a formula wouldn't work as the values changes weekly so might appear in different places, I was using the code to just update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hi thanks for this, the problem being though the values are changing, so the name in sheet 1 might be in in "A1" but then in sheet 2 be in "F12" and then next week could be in "F14" so its just a way of using the code to update accordingly, also used your vba and still no luck :( – Calum 9 mins ago

A formula is the right way to go. You can use `COUNTIF` to check for the existence. Put this formula in cell M1 and pull it down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F$1:$F$14000,A1)>0,"Yes","No")
```

However if you still want to use code, try this (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim name1 As Variant, name2 As Variant, answer(1 To 14000) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        name1 = .Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("A1:A14000").Value
        name2 = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F14000").Value

        For i = 1 To 14000
            If IsInArray(name1(i, 1), name2) Then answer(i) = "Yes" Else answer(i) = "No"
        Next i

        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M1").Resize(UBound(answer), 1).Value = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(answer)
    End With
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim bDimen As Byte, i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(UBound(arr, 2)) Then bDimen = 1 Else bDimen = 2
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case bDimen
    Case 1
        On Error Resume Next
        IsInArray = Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Case 2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
            IsInArray = Application.Match(stringToBeFound, Application.Index(arr, , i), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If IsInArray = True Then Exit For
        Next
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this,
the problem being though the values are changing, so the name in sheet 1 might be in in "A1" but then in sheet 2 be in "F12" and then next week could be in "F14" so its just a way of using the code to update accordingly, also used your vba and still no luck :(

Comment: Oh so you want to check if it is ANYWHERE in the 2nd column?

Answer (score 0):

You are first assigning a value to `answer(i)` from  the `Worksheet` and then assigning the `Yes` value if it matches.

However this value gets assigned to `answer()` not to the `Cell`.

you need to change:

```
answer(i) = "yes"
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet0").Cells(i, 13).Value = "yes"
```

and remove `answer()` completely.

---

The better way would be this:

```
=IF(A1=F1;"Yes";"No")
```